# Merge several pre-sorted lists into a joint list in most effective way (and taking top elements of it )

Tags: algorithm, list, linked-list

I have such a pre-set:

- many pre-sorted ordered lists, e.g., 1000 elements each sorted by a criteria (for instance, "last" based on a time)
- need to make a joint list that maintains sort order and also contains 1000 last elements (so can discard elements of original lists that do not fit into top 1000). 
  However, selecting 1000 top can be done separately as well.
- merging needs to be as fast, as efficient as possible. Re-sorting full merged list is not an option.

Comment: Using 1 loop compare the items of the 3 list by having 3 separate indices for each list. Insert the smallest item to your join list. Increment the index of the list where you found the smallest item. Loop again until the join list is 1000.

Comment: And where are you stuck?

Comment: @Lino I have removed the tags. Still, this is an algorithmic question and is perfectly valid. Wiki, for instance, lists dozens of list sorting algorithms and finding a best one with the help of the experts is a most normal thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use any [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue)-based data structure:

```
priority queue q = empty
for each list add first element to q
create an array next that contains next elements for every list (initially next element is a second element)

while result list is not full
    take top element from the q and add to the result list
    add next element of the corresponding list to the q (if any)
    update next element of the corresponding list
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is known as Merge k sorted arrays.
In java, it is quit simple to resolve it. Just add elements into a sortedSet(the add to the sorted set is fast). And stop when you reach the 1000 top.

```
SortedSet<Integer> s = new TreeSet<>();
//s1,s2,s3 are the input lists here
int n = Math.max(Math.max(s2.size(), s1.size()), s3.size());
for (int i = 0; i < n || s.size() <= limit; i++) {
    if (s1.get(i) != null) {
        s.add(s1.get(i));
    }
    if (s2.get(i) != null) {
        s.add(s2.get(i));
    }
    if (s3.get(i) != null) {
        s.add(s3.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: This code does not solve the task. It just takes ⌈limit / k⌉ first elements from each list and sorts them.